# Hyperparameter tuning with AI Platfrom tries same values multiple times

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I have a small machine learning model on Google AI Platform. It accepts several input features and predicts one output. Hyperparameter tuning is used to try different sets of input features to see what works better and my config (yaml) file looks like this:

```
trainingInput:
 scaleTier: STANDARD_1
 hyperparameters:
 goal: MINIMIZE
 maxTrials: 4
 maxParallelTrials: 1
 hyperparameterMetricTag: rmse
 params:
   parameterName: feature_set
   type: CATEGORICAL
   categoricalValues: ["people_per_bedroom", "num_rooms,housing_median_age", "num_rooms,housing_median_age,people_per_bedroom", "num_rooms"]
```

It seems to work, but I am confused to see that AI Platform has tried some values two times and others hasn't tried at all.

[image]

Could somebody clarify this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default algorithm used by AI Platform hyperparameter tuning is a Bayesian optimization algorithm. If you'd like to try all possible values for the `feature_set` parameter, you can change the algorithm field to `GRID_SEARCH` in your hyperparameter spec.

Here's the docs on algorithm types: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#Algorithm